# Remove the dash from a negative number

Tags: angular

When I display the negative number for example `-0.24%`... I would like to remove the dash please.
I don't know how to change it ?

I don't need of the dash because I have a red arrow.

[image]

I don't know if the probleme is here to remove the dash?

```
<div class="" style="width: 20% !important;">
    <h5 style="text-align: right;">
      {{ n.variation | number:'1.2-2' | projectformatnum }}&nbsp;%
      <span *ngIf="n.variation < 0"
      style="
         background: url(/assets/images/project-online-sprites.png) 1px -834px no-repeat; 
         position: relative; 
         top: 3px;
         margin-left: 10px;">
    </span>
    </h5>
</div>
```

Comment: You can transform your negative number into a positive number using Math.abs(yourVariableWithNumber);

Comment: Have you consider that your logic is wrong? It's not about removing a dash but about `variation` being negative. If the value would be for instance -50%, you don't want to change a negative value into a positive one and show the users the wrong information.

Comment: @Ricardo Machado: Thank you Ricardo, I am beginner where I have to put `Math.abs(n.variation)` on my code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a custom pipe:

By angular-cli: `ng g pipe abs`

```
@Pipe({name: 'abs'})

export class abs implements PipeTransform {
  transform(num: number, args?: any): any {
    return Math.abs(num);
  }
}
```

you can change your template as:

```
{{ n.variation | number:'1.2-2' | projectformatnum | abs }}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use **Math.abs** function for this.

Example

```
n.variation // -0.24

Math.abs(n.variation) // 0.24
```

Comment: Thank you Said, I am beginner where I have to put `Math.abs(n.variation)` on my code ?

Comment: In your component when you want to assign a value to n.variation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use also conditional operator before pipe the number

```
{{ (n.variation<0?-n.variation:n.variation) | number:'1.2-2' | projectformatnum }}
```

Or in your pipe projectformatnum use some similar to return always a positive number formated (I don't know about your pipe)